# Print syntax help for printing long Array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

```
while(i>=j);
                System.out.println("-----------------------");
                       System.out.print("[");
                        for(int x=0; x<=n+r; x++){
                         System.out.print ((arrPascal[n+r][x])+",");
                }
                System.out.print("]");
        }
```

My code prints

```
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1, ]
```

I want to print

```
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
```

Tried print statement:

```
System.out.print (Arrays.toString(arrPascal[n+r][x]))
```

Results in error:

```
The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (long)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution it ignores to print the "," if its the last element. Hope it would help.

```
while(i>=j);
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
                   System.out.print("[");
                    for(int x=0; x<=n+r; x++){
                    
                     System.out.print ((arrPascal[n+r][x]));
                     if(x<n+r){
                     System.out.print(",");

                     }
            }
            System.out.print("]");
    }
```

Edit 1:
Rather than the above approach you should go for:

```
int arrPascal[] = {1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1};  
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrPascal));
```

Output

```
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
```

If you have to print a nested array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrPascal));
```